# How to use connectToPort api of AS400 class in jt400.jar api

Tags: ibm-midrange, jt400, jtopen

I need to connect to as400 system on a specific port. I am using connectToPort method. But it is not connecting.

With out using this api, If I just use the 
AS400 aS400 = new AS400(mHost);
aS400.authenticate(user,pwd);// this is successful and connecting to port 8475
 aS400.connectToPort(someotherPortNumber); // this call is no returning back

With this, I see that it is connecting to the port 8475 on the host.
But If I want to give the port number of my choice, what is the way.
I tried using connectToPort(portNo); and is not working for me.
Please help.
I am using jt400.jar of version as

Name: com/ibm/as400/access/
Specification-Title: IBM Toolbox for Java
Specification-Version: 7.3.0.6
Specification-Vendor: IBM Corporation
Implementation-Title: com.ibm.as400.access
Implementation-Version: JTOpen 9.6
Implementation-Vendor: IBM Corporation and others

Thanks in advance
Madhavi

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are changing the AS400 to listen on another port before you try connecting to that port right?